# sed - how to replace a pattern after specific pattern with a word between

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file having lines with below content

```
name : 'last1, first1', phone : '1111111111', email :'test123@mail.com', name: 'last2,first2', phone : '2222222222', email: 'test234@mail.com',name: 'last3,first3', phone : '3333333333', email:'test456@mail.com
```

Have to replace like this.

```
last name : 'last1', first name : 'first1', phone : '1111111111', email :'test123@mail.com', last name: 'last2', first name : 'first2', phone : '2222222222', email: 'test234@mail.com',last name: 'last3, first name: 'first3', phone : '3333333333', email:'test456@mail.com
```

There are lot of questions around sed replace but couldn't find any response to solve this one. If there is any, provide me the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing your string into `sed` with the following regex:

```
sed -e "s_name : '\([a-zA-Z 0-9]*\),\([a-zA-Z 0-9]*\)',\(.*\)_last name : '\1', first name '\2', \3_"
```

Gives this result.

```
last name : 'last1', first name ' first1',  phone : '1111111111', email :'test123@mail.com', name: 'last2,first2', phone : '2222222222', email: 'test234@mail.com',name: 'last3,first3', phone : '3333333333', email:'test456@mail.com
```

**EDIT**:

There was an inconsistency in your input: the first instance of `name` was followed by a space and a colon, while the other instances only had the colon, not the space. Here an updated version that takes that into account:

```
sed -e "s_name *: '\([a-zA-Z 0-9]*\),\([a-zA-Z 0-9]*\)',_last name: '\1', first name: '\2', _g"
```

gives:

```
last name: 'last1', first name: ' first1',  phone : '1111111111', email :'test123@mail.com', last name: 'last2', first name" 'first2',  phone : '2222222222', email: 'test234@mail.com',last name: 'last3', first name: 'first3',  phone : '3333333333', email:'test456@mail.com
```

Comment: Only first occurence of name is replaced here.

Comment: This command is not able to replace all the occurrences of name. Only first occurrence is updated.

Comment: @sree if you are satisfied with the answer, you may accept it so that others know that no further help is required.

Comment: Is there a way to get element name as last_name, first_name in the output?

Comment: Never mind.. I got this worked for getting last_name, first_name in the output with this command.   sed -E ":a;s/name *: '([^,]*), *([^,]*)'(.*)/last_name : '\1', first_name: \2\3/;ta;s/(first_name: )([^,]*) *,/\1'\2'/g"

Comment: This also worked: sed -e "s/name *: '\([a-zA-Z 0-9]*\),\([a-zA-Z 0-9]*\)',/last_name: '\1', first_name: '\2', /g"